# xslt 2.0 insert node in upper level

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<A>
    <B>
        <C>12</C>
        <C>44</C>
        <C>221</C>
    </B>
    <D>
        <E></E>
        <F></F>
        <INFO>hello world</INFO>
    </D>
</A>
```

And currently I'm in template for `C` nodes

```
<xsl:template match="A/B/C">
...
</xsl:template>
```

How to add a new node in upper level **while you're inside** `A/B/C` template

I want to add node `<USER>` after `<INFO>` node

So it will be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<A>
    <B>
        <C>12</C>
        <C>44</C>
        <C>221</C>
    </B>
    <D>
        <E></E>
        <F></F>
        <INFO>hello world</INFO>
        <USER>root</USER>
    </D>
</A>
```

Comment: If you want to recreate the input structure in the output and want to add a child element to the `D` element then you would do that in a template matching `D` or matching the last child (e.g. `INFO`). Why do you want to add new nodes in the template matching `C`? And how do the other templates for ancestors of `C` look? Which part of the input tree do they output?

Comment: @MartinHonnen it's because the XML has many `C` nodes and only one `D` node. template for `C` has a complex logic, it checks data for every `C`. Depending of the logic result I need to create a node after node `D`. If I'll try to do this in template for `D` I would need to use something like `<xsl:for-each select="../B/C">-logic-</xsl:for-each>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to add a new node in upper level while you're inside A/B/C template

You can't. In XSLT, the result tree nodes are written IN ORDER. You have complete freedom to access anything in the source tree at any time, so you need to structure your stylesheet according to the structure of the output, and at the point where you might want to add a node, you need at that point to find the conditions for whether to output it.

If there's a serious structure clash that makes this difficult, consider doing a multi-pass transformation.